# Reordering x categories in ggplot2 only works with descending order

Tags: r, ggplot2, categories

I am making a bar plot with a character variable as x, a numeric variable as y and a character variable as fill. I want to order the x categories by the fill variable, but it only works with descending reorder.

I've been extensively searching around and I find everywhere that reorder(x, z) should order the x categories according to the ascending order of z, while reorder(x,-z) or reorder(x, desc(z)) should order the x categories according to the descending order of z.
In my case, I only get the categories ordered by z when using desc(z); reorder(x, -z) returns an error (! invalid argument to unary operator), and using z simply orders them by x.

This code gives almost what I want:

```
df<- data.frame(x=c("loc9","loc2", "loc3","loc7","loc5","loc6","loc4","loc1","loc8"), y=c(1,2,5,3,5,6,7,9,5), z=c("A","A", "B","B","B","B","C","C","C"), se=c(0.1, 0.14, 0.2, 1,0.25,0.3,0.21,0.23,0.2), n=c(2,2,3,2,1,1,3,5,4))
plot<- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(x, desc(z)), y=y, fill=z))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(reorder(x, desc(z)), ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=0.3, colour="blue3", alpha =0.9, size=0.7)+
  geom_text(aes(x=reorder(x, desc(z)), y=0.5, label=n))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",plot.title = element_text(size=12),
        text = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))+
  ggtitle("Here the title of the plot") +
  labs(x="", ylab="Lab of y", fill=NULL)
```

[image]

The following code gives me 36 warnings (In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA) and produces the following figure.

```
plot<- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(x, desc(z)), y=y, fill=z))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(reorder(x, desc(z)), ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=0.3, colour="blue3", alpha =0.9, size=0.7)+
  geom_text(aes(x=reorder(x, desc(z)), y=0.5, label=n))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",plot.title = element_text(size=12),
        text = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))+
  ggtitle("Here the title of the plot") +
  labs(x="", ylab="Lab of y", fill=NULL)
plot
```

This code gives me 36 warnings (In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA) and produces the following figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Think this should work!

```
df$z <- factor(df$z, levels=c("A", "B"  , "C"))

df = df[order(df$z, df$x), ]

df$x = factor(df$x, levels = unique(df$x))

plot<- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ geom_errorbar(aes(x, ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=0.3, colour="blue3", alpha =0.9, size=0.7)+ geom_text(aes(x=x, y=0.5, label=n))

plot
```

Update: Or use fct_reorder (forcats) to order alphabetically

```
plot<- df %>% ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x,z), y=y, fill=z)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ geom_errorbar(aes(x, ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=0.3, colour="blue3", alpha =0.9, size=0.7)+ geom_text(aes(x=x, y=0.5, label=n))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, alexandradevon, your solution works smoothly. I was aware it can be worked around by using factor. In fact, it seems the df = df[order(df$z, df$x), ] part is not needed, at least it works perfectly for me in this case. In fact, I also tried by pre-ordering the data.frame with arrange(z,x), which does not work at all. So, it seems the ordering of the data.frame is irrelevant.
But I still would be interested in understanding what is going on with reorder, as I see it repeatedly used in many examples with the same syntaxis I use for ascending orders.

Comment: I've been playing around a little bit more, and I found that it is only the ordering of x which does the trick. Odd enough, converting to factor and ordering z does not affect the order of its categories in the figure and legend. But, converting x to factor in itself is enough to get the desired figure.
The question on reorder, remains, though.

Comment: I later found out that the only reason why converting x to factor was enough for getting the desire output was that z was ordered from its definition. I shuffle it a little bit and then I needed the three statements proposed by alexandradevon. I'll try to avoid this kind of ordering in future examples. Sorry for messing around.

Comment: You can also use this: `plot<- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x,z), y=y, fill=z))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ geom_errorbar(aes(x, ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=0.3, colour="blue3", alpha =0.9, size=0.7)+ geom_text(aes(x=x, y=0.5, label=n))

plot`

Comment: I think the main issue is that reorder is typically used for numeric columns while fct_reorder (forcats) works well for categorical columns